# EJB 3.1 or Spring 3.. When to choose which one?

Tags: comparison, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, spring-3

EJB achieved many improvements in 3.x versions, Spring is also commonly used and version 3 is a good alternative.

There are many articles on web, but no exact comparison about ejb3x versus spring3x.. Do you have any ideas about them, in real world examples which one is better at which conditions?

For example, we want to separate db and server, which means our application will be on a server, our database will be in another server.. EJB remoting vs Cluster4Spring etc ?

Doing everyting @Annotation is always good? configuration never needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EJB3 or "Spring3 + hibernate" which one suitable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998484/ejb3-or-spring3-hibernate-which-one-suitable)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For your use case where the application runs on one server and the database runs on another, the choice between EJB and Spring is irrelevant. Every platforms supports this, be it a Java SE application, a simple Servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty, PHP, Ruby on Rails, or whatever.

You don't need any kind of explicit remoting for that. You just define a datasource, provide the URL where your DB server lives and that's it.

That said, both EJB and Spring Beans do make it easier to work with datasources. They both help you defining a datasource, injecting it in beans and managing transactions associated with them.

Of the two, EJB (and Java EE in general) is more lightweight and adheres more to the convention over configuration principle. Spring requires more verbosity to get the same things and depends a lot on XML files which can quickly become very big and unwieldy. The flip side of the coin is that Spring can be less magical and you might feel more in control after having everything you want spelled out.

Another issue is the way EJB and Spring are developed.

EJB is free (as in free beer), open-source and non-proprietary. There are implementations of EJB being made by non profit organizations (Apache), open source companies (Redhat/JBoss) and deeply commercial closed source enterprises (IBM). I personally would avoid the latter, but to each his own.

Spring on the other hand is free and open-source, but strongly proprietary. There is only one company making Spring and that's Springsource. If you don't agree with Rod, then tough luck for you. This is not necessarily a bad thing, but a difference you might want to be aware of.

> Doing everyting @Annotation is always good? configuration never needed?

It's an endless debate really. Some argue that XML is hard to maintain, others argue that annotations pollute an otherwise pure POJO model.

I think that annotating a bean as being an EJB stateless bean (@Stateless) or a JPA entity (@Entity) is more cleanly done using annotations. Same goes for the @EJB or @Inject dependency injections. On the other hand, I prefer JPQL named queries to be in XML files instead of annotations, and injections that represent pure configuration data (like a max value for something) to be in XML as well.

In Java EE, every annotation can also be specified in XML. If both the annotation and the XML equivalent are present, the XML overrules the annotation. This makes it really convenient to start with an annotation for the default case, but override it later via XML for a specific use case.

The current preference in Java EE seems to be more towards (simple) annotations combined with a large amount of convention over configuration.

Comment: akira, thanks your your detailed answer, i am a bit confused about remoting. when they are needed? in situations that remoting needed, does Spring have capabilities that EJB can do with @remote beans? - I can ask it in another question if you want..

Answer (score 14):

The real question you should be asking is **CDI/EJB or Spring**

Answer (score 6):

It's often not Spring vs EJB, but Spring vs Java EE. EJB itself compares to Spring Beans. Both of them are a kind of managed beans running inside a container (the EJB container resp. Spring container).

Overall the two technologies are rather similar. Reza Rahman did a great comparison between the two a while back.

Comment: Being nearly a year ago I can't quite remember which one I exactly referenced, but it was indeed something like that one.

Comment: The document is from 2007. I'm sure a lot has changed, especially with Java 6 EE.

Comment: Java EE 6 introduced CDI, so that's a major change indeed. EJB changed less dramatically from 3.0 to 3.1, so large parts of the comparison may still be valid. The local view (no required business interface) and being able to reside everywhere (instead of in a special EJB module) were the most important changes for that comparison.

Answer (score 6):

EJB's are more advantageous because of standardization. If you are working with a lightweight application I think going with Spring is fine but if you expect that your application will be big and will require lots of memory access and data connections access you may consider starting your development with EJBs. The main reason being clustering and load balancing are built into the EJB framework.

In an EJB environment, when an EAR ('E'nterprise 'AR'chive) is deployed, it may be deployed with multiple EJBs beans that each could have a specific purpose. Let say you wrote a bean for user management and another bean for product management. Maybe one day you find that your user services way exceed your products access services, and you want to move your user bean to a different server on a different machine. This can actually be done in runtime without altering your code. Beans can be moved between servers and databases, to accomodate clustering and load/data balancing without affecting your developers or your users because most of it can be configured at the deployment level.

Another reason for supporting a standard is knowing that most large third party vendors will likely support it resulting in less issues when integrating with new standard/service/technology - and let's face it, those come out like new flavours of ice-cream. And if it is in a public specification new start-up companies or kind developers can create an open-source version.

http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/06/29/spring-ejb3.html

It is most unfortunate that even the most intelligent designers or programmers cannot predict which of their features may or may not be embraced by the development community which is the main reason software becomes bloated... Java EE is definitely that!

Answer (score 4):

Choose one or the other, but not both.

My personal preference is Spring.  I've used on projects with great success for the past six years.  It's as solid as any software out there.

Spring can work with EJBs if you choose to have them in your app, but I don't believe the reverse is true.

I would recommend separate physical machines for web, app, and database servers if you can afford it.

Spring can work with several remoting options, including SOAP and REST web services.  A comparison of Spring beans with EJB is beyond the scope of this question.  I don't see what it has to do with your implementation.  If you use Spring POJO services they're in-memory rather than requiring another network hop like remote EJBs.  Think of Fowler's Law of Distributed Objects: "Don't".  Only introduce latency with good reason.

Comment: hi, duffymo, thanks for your quick response. do you have an idea about seperating app/web servers and database? We have to do an implementation like this so does Spring have options(Spring has RMI solution i think) compared to EJB remote beans?

Comment: Sure, put the database on a separate server and have the Java code on the app server make a JDBC connection.  You don't need RMI or remote beans.  POJOs can do it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd mention unit testing here.
In common web application (controller->service->data->...->view) EJB and Spring both provide similar result, but spring offers easier testing.

In my humble experience the way you develop is different in couple of aspects:

- Unit test (spring wins). In spring its done pretty stright forward, while in ejb you have to use Arqullian with ShrinkWrap (sic!) which is slow to run on every build.
- Persistence (ejb wins). In spring there is struggle around it, i.e. google "how to autowire persistence in entity listener" http://bit.ly/1P6u5WO
- Configuration (ejb wins). As newbie coming to spring from ejb I was surprised by swarm of annotations and .xml files.

Answer (score 2):

EJB 3.1 is the best while being the standard for Java 6 EE applications.

Spring still does not support Java 6 CDI(weld) also still depends a lot on XML configuration.  EJB 3.1 is powerful and smart.

I think that Spring 3.1 doesn't need any XML configuration.  You have the option to use annotations for configuration.